# Templated function Return type at compile time no arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that right now can return a value of a certain type for me. It looks like this

```
template<typename T>
T getNullValue(){
    if(std::is_same<T,long long>::value){
        return NULL_LONG;
    }else if(std::is_same<T,double>::value){
        return NULL_DOUBLE;
    }

}
```

This works but I do not like it resolving at run time as opposed to compile time but this allows me to do

```
double x = getNullValue<double>();
long long y = getNullValue<long long>();
```

How can I make it so that I can just overload different versions of getNullValue depending on what I want to return without having to resolve that at runtime.

```
getNullValue<type i need>();
```

Comment: Please note that this code is optimal if compiled with optimization. You can do the "elegant" template overloading but it makes the code more complicated than it should be.

Comment: The easy answer is `if constexpr` and nothing else has to change.

Comment: are  you saying if i do "if constexpr (std::is_same .... )" then it is resolved at compile time?

Comment: Tatsuyuki is there a way I can verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template specialization should do the trick nicely.  An optimizing compiler *should* convert this to a simple assignment.

```
// getNullValue.hpp :

template <class T>
T getNullValue() {
   return 0;
}

// remember to declare specialization in header or strange linking errors may occur
template <> long long getNullValue<long long>()
template <> double getNullValue<double>()


 // getNullValue.cpp:

 template <> long long getNullValue<long long>() {
   return NULL_LONG;
 }
template <> double getNullValue<double>() {
   return NULL_DOUBLE;
}

int main() {
    double x = getNullValue<double>();
    long long y = getNullValue<long long>();
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization for more examples of specialization.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed!